# Facebook API search through user posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

With the new facebook graph api in order to get my posts I have to call the /feed/me method. And this is going to retrieve me a list with my posts.

The question : is there any way to search through my posts for a specific keyword or hashtag?

Thanks

Comment: There is no way to search.

Comment: I could just try to search myself through the posts but I'm pretty sure that there is a limit for retrieving feed posts. What if I want feeds older then a specific period ? Are they lost,  so I cannot retrieve them using the api ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want only your own posts, you can call /me/posts. But If you want also others' post on your wall, you must call /me/feed. You can take a look at  [graph api documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed).

For the search, you can do it by call Facebook API in a programming language. When the response is returned, you can retrieve all your posts'messages or stories. You can search those strings(message, story) for keywords of your choice. I think Facebook API doesn't let you search for keywords in posts.

Comment: /me/feed doesn't exists anymore. No way to get a users feed

Comment: You can do it for your own profile, if you get an access token with the right permissions. I have checked.

Comment: The permission you need is user_posts.

Comment: That doesn't give the users feed. It just give the users own posts.

Comment: The question was how can I search through my posts for a specific keyword or hashtag.

Comment: Nobody knows a solution for searching through user's feeds ?